# Texstudio: BibTeX can't open .bib file

Tags: bibtex, texstudio, jabref

I have tried searching for two consecutive days, and read multiple treads, but no one seems to answer my question exactly. I am using MiKTeX 2.9, TeXstudio and Jabref 2.9. Here is a minimal code example:

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  In this paper I will try to sucessfully make a reference 
  \cite{hardin1968tragedy}
\end{abstract}

\section{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibli}

\end{document}
```

This always returns the following errorlog from BibTeX:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
>   The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
>   The style file: plain.bst
>   I couldn't open database file bibli.bib
>   ---line 4 of file test.aux
>   : \bibdata{bibli
>   :               }
>   I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
>   I found no database files---while reading file test.aux
>   Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "hardin1968tragedy"
>   (There were 2 error messages)

My bib file contains my citation when checked, but my `.bbl`file is empty save for:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\end{thebibliography}
```

All the files in the example are contained in a **separate** directory. I have also tried compiling in quite possibly every way imaginable.

Comment: Is the aux-file in the same directory as your tex file?

Comment: Is your bib file, `bibli.bib`, located either in the same directory as our main .tex file is, or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX?

Comment: All the files in the example, including the .bib-file and the .aux file are contained in a separate folder created for this example.

Comment: Can you tell us the full path of your `.tex` file and the full path of the `.bib` one? Moreover, is `bibli.bib` or `biblio.bib` the name of your bibliography? Sorry for these silly questions, but one never knows.

Comment: .tex path: C:\Users\Eier\LaTeX\test.tex  
.bib path: C:\Users\Eier\LaTeX\bibli.bib

Comment: What happens if you move the tex and the bib to a new folder outside the user profile, e.g. `C:\TeX-tests\...`? Also what happens if you change the style plain to e.g. alpha. Does the error message then also mention alpha?

Comment: Tried both. The error does not mention alpha and changing the folder paths does not work either.  
BTW: I get the exact same error on my older laptop, which is running Windows Vista (this one is running Win7)

Comment: (1) Delete all auxiliary files and try from the command line (which I'm sure you've done already, but...). (2) Create a new `.bib` file in the same working directory and test if that one works (make the appropriate changes in your `.tex` file).

Comment: If the error doesn't mention alpha then obviously pdflatex/bibtex is not processing the new test.tex. Check if you have set a "master file".

Comment: I have tried setting the .tex as the master file, no result. I have also tried deleting all auxiliary files and create a new .bib file. I get the exact same error with the new .bib file.

Comment: I didn't mean that you set your tex file as master file but that you check if another file (with the same name) is set as master file and so compiled. This was the only way I could reproduce your problem (assuming that bibli.bib really exists, that its name is correct and  that it is in the correct folder). Btw you should add @UlrikeFischer to your comments so that I get notified.

Comment: Perhaps this is not going to solve your specific problem, but I also was having a similar problem in TexStudio.

The addition of \clearpage prior to the bibliography command solved my problem.  No idea why this solved the issue.